# How to handle resources like images in your own node package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am developing a *webapp* with **NodeJS** and **webpack**. It uses also **ReactJS** as a dependency. So let's call it simple ui webapp.

In my package.json I reference a package as a dependency which I want to use in the app. This package is not from npm, but it is developed by myself and resides on the same filesystem, local, which totally works fine. I am developing this package, lets call it *ui-elements* and the *webapp* in parallel, because I know I have to use the *ui-elements* in 10 about following *webapp*-style projects.

Back to the problem: The package gets imported when I `npm install`, so I have my local package inside the `node_modules` dir. Good.

This *ui-elements*-package is also bundled with webpack and contains some React components that use images as background images. Now, when I run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack` inside the package folder (while developing the *ui-elements* package) the file-loader emits the resources into the `res/` folder, like I want it to be in the webpack.config.js from the *ui-elements* package.

But since I want to use the *ui-elements* package inside my *webapp*, the resources reside deep inside the `node_modules/` dir (`node_modules/ui-elements/res`).

**My question:**

How should my `webpack.config.js` in the *webapp* project be altered, to get the image resolving by the browser working?

And, am I thinking too complicated? I just want to build and use a package (containing some ui elements with background images), that i can reuse in React *webapp*s. Is there a better approach?

I will paste the extracts of the webpack configs of both projects:

**ui-elements**

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: __dirname
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        use: [
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'res/img/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
  }
};
```

**webapp**

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'webapp.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        use: [
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    /*
     * this entry makes me use a local working tree of the
     * ui-elements package, which makes working easier, i don't
     * have to switch projects, rebuild the package and update my
     * dependencies in this webapp project
     */
    /*
    alias: {
      "ui-elements": path.resolve(__dirname, 'libDev'),
    },
    */
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      // path.resolve(__dirname, 'libDev'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
  }
};
```

Comment: when you open the webpage, what url does the ui-elements image resources point to?

Comment: res/img/background.png ... but the res folder is not available in the webapp's scope.